# Batch script to iterate CALL command for multi-valued variables

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have a batch file **oldmaster.bat**:

```
@echo off

cd E:\data\utilities

>E:\data\output.log (

REM Maintain property for app1

call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app1" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=1" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app1" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=13" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app1" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=22" DATASYNC
..................
..................
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app1" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=N" DATASYNC

REM Maintain property for app2

call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app2" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=1" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app2" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=13" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app2" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=22" DATASYNC
..................
..................
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app2" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=N" DATASYNC

REM Maintain property for appN

call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=appN" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=1" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=appN" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=13" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=appN" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=22" DATASYNC
..................
..................
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=appN" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=N" DATASYNC
)
```

As you can see, in **master.bat**:
1.Varibales *Username (testuser), password (testuserpassword), Start range (2018-10-01), End range(2019-11-01)* are always same/contant for each line of `call` command.
2.Only variables *Application* and *type* are changing its values based on the logic of calling executescript for each *application* and each *type* combination.

Whenever there is a new Application or type or start range or end range, I need to modify the master.bat script and update so many lines manually which is a tiresome process.

Now, to make the process simpler I have created following four text files as an inputs to my **master.bat** file.

**logindetail.txt:**

`testuser,testuserpassword`

**application.txt:**

`app1,app2,app3...appN`

**range.txt:**

`2018-10-01,2019-11-01`

**type.txt:**

`1,13,22...N`

Using above input text files, I want to create a batch script where I need not to write `call` command so many times to iterate it for *N applications* and *N types*.

I have written below code to achieve the same:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

cd E:\data\utilities

rem.> record.log

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (logindetail.txt) do (
set "username=%%a"
set "password=%%b"
)

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (range.txt) do (
set "startrange=%%i"
set "endrange=%%j" 
)

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=," %%m in (application.txt) DO (
set "appname=%%m"
)

for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%n in (type.txt) do (
set "apptype=%%n"
)

echo call executescript %username% %password% "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=%appname%" "Start range=%startrange%" "End range=%endrange%" "Select type=%apptype%" DATASYNC >>record.log
```

My **current record.log** is coming like below which I understand its simply putting all the comma seperated values of *Application* and *type* variables in one row:

`call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app1,app2,app3,...appN" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=1,13,22,...N" DATASYNC`

But I want my **record.log** to look exactly same as below, so that I can be sure that **newmaster.bat** will be doing exactly same as **oldmaster.bat** does:

**expected record.log:**

```
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app1" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=1" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app1" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=13" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app1" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=22" DATASYNC
..................
..................
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app1" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=N" DATASYNC

call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app2" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=1" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app2" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=13" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app2" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=22" DATASYNC
..................
..................
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=app2" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=N" DATASYNC

call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=appN" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=1" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=appN" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=13" DATASYNC
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=appN" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=22" DATASYNC
..................
..................
call executescript testuser testuserpassword "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=appN" "Start range=2018-10-01" "End range=2019-11-01" "Select type=N" DATASYNC
```

Could you please help me fix my code to achieve the expected result?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, this is how I would do it:

```
@echo off
set "user=testuser"
set "password=testuserpassword"
set "start=2018-10-01"
set "end=2019-11-01"

for %%f in (app1 app2 app3) do (
    for %%i in (1 13 22) do (
      echo call executescript %user% %password% "MaintainAppProperty" "Application=%%f" "Start range=%start%" "End range=%end%" "Select type=%%i" DATASYNC
   )
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
)>>record.log
```

`echo` in the `echo call execution...` line is just for demonstration purpose, you can remove it from the line once you are happy with the results and once you have ammended the real application names. for now, you can run this as is to see the results.

Comment: Thanks Gerhard! It's very helpful.